# How do you simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How do you simplify: $\sqrt{2019C2+2692C2+2020C2+2691C2}$ where $C$ denotes the combination function?

My though on this is to convert everything to 
$\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Is this a correct approach or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It is equal to $$3 \sqrt{1257538}$$

Comment: The only way is to compute each term individually.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $nC2=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ (by easy use of the definition).

Then, the required expression equals :

$$\sqrt{2019C2+2692C2+2020C2+2691C2}$$

$$=\sqrt{2019\left(\frac{2018}{2}\right)+2692\left(\frac{2691}{2}\right)+2020\left(\frac{2019}{2}\right)+2691\left(\frac{2690}{2}\right)}$$

$$=\sqrt{2019^2+2691^2}$$

$$=3\sqrt{1257538}$$